# How do you build an infinite grid like data structure in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, tying-the-knot

I am trying to form an infinite grid like data structure by tying the knot.

This is my approach:

```
import Control.Lens

data Grid a = Grid {_val :: a,
                    _left :: Grid a,
                    _right :: Grid a,
                    _down :: Grid a,
                    _up :: Grid a}

makeLenses ''Grid

makeGrid :: Grid Bool -- a grid with all Falses
makeGrid = formGrid Nothing Nothing Nothing Nothing

formGrid :: Maybe (Grid Bool) -> Maybe (Grid Bool) -> Maybe (Grid Bool) -> Maybe (Grid Bool) -> Grid Bool
formGrid ls rs ds us = center
  where
    center = Grid False leftCell rightCell downCell upCell
    leftCell = case ls of
                Nothing -> formGrid Nothing (Just center) Nothing Nothing
                Just l ->  l
    rightCell = case rs of
                Nothing -> formGrid (Just center) Nothing Nothing Nothing
                Just r ->  r
    upCell = case us of
                Nothing -> formGrid Nothing Nothing (Just center) Nothing
                Just u ->  u
    downCell = case ds of
                Nothing -> formGrid Nothing Nothing Nothing (Just center)
                Just d ->  d
```

For some reason, this is not working. As seen here:

```
*Main> let testGrid = (set val True) . (set (right . val) True) $ makeGrid
*Main> _val $ _right $ _left testGrid
False
*Main> _val $ _left $ _right testGrid
False
*Main> _val $ testGrid
True
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When you `set val True`, you're not modifying in place, but creating a copy. `makeGrid` constructs a grid where everything is `False`, including `center -> right -> left`. When you `set val True` on the center, you're creating a copy `center'` where `val center' == True`, but `_right center' == _right center`, and therefore `_left $ _right center' == _left $ _right center == False`.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin That deserves to be the answer; it's what I was just starting to write.

Comment: @cirdec I didn't feel like it answered the question, since the question was "how do you do it", not "why didn't my attempt work". But seeing how you've deleted your answer, I'll make my comment into one. :-)

Answer (score 7):

@Fyodor's answer explains why your current approach won't work.

One common way of accomplishing this in functional languages is using
[zippers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure))
(not to be confused with `zip` or related functions).

The idea is that the zipper is a representation of the data structure
focused on a particular portion (e.g., a cell in the grid).  You can
apply transformations to the zipper to "move" this focus around, and
you can apply different transformations to query or "mutate" the data structure
relative to the focus.  Both types of transformations are purely
functional -- they act on an immutable zipper and just
create a new copy.

Here, you can start with a zipper for an infinite list with position
information:

```
data Zipper a = Zipper [a] a Int [a] deriving (Functor)
  -- Zipper ls x n rs represents the doubly-infinite list (reverse ls ++
  -- [x] ++ rs) viewed at offset n
instance (Show a) => Show (Zipper a) where
  show (Zipper ls x n rs) =
    show (reverse (take 3 ls)) ++ " " ++ show (x,n) ++ " " ++ show (take 3 rs)
```

This `Zipper` is intended to be a representation of a doubly infinite
list (i.e., a list that's infinite in both directions).  An example
would be:

```
> Zipper [-10,-20..] 0 0 [10,20..]
[-30,-20,-10] (0,0) [10,20,30]
```

This is intended to represent the list of all (positive and negative)
integer multiples of ten focused at value `0`, position `0` and it actually uses two Haskell infinite lists, one for each direction.

You can
define functions to move the focus forward or back:

```
back, forth :: Zipper a -> Zipper a
back (Zipper (l:ls) x n rs)  = Zipper ls l (n-1) (x:rs)
forth (Zipper ls x n (r:rs)) = Zipper (x:ls) r (n+1) rs
```

so that:

```
> forth $ Zipper [-10,-20..] 0 0 [10,20..]
[-20,-10,0] (10,1) [20,30,40]
> back $ back $ Zipper [-10,-20..] 0 0 [10,20..]
[-50,-40,-30] (-20,-2) [-10,0,10]
>
```

Now, a `Grid` can be represented as a zipper of rows, with each row a
zipper of values:

```
newtype Grid a = Grid (Zipper (Zipper a)) deriving (Functor)
instance Show a => Show (Grid a) where
  show (Grid (Zipper ls x n rs)) =
    unlines $ zipWith (\a b -> a ++ " " ++ b)
              (map show [n-3..n+3])
              (map show (reverse (take 3 ls) ++ [x] ++ (take 3 rs)))
```

together with a set of focus-moving functions:

```
up, down, right, left :: Grid a -> Grid a
up (Grid g) = Grid (back g)
down (Grid g) = Grid (forth g)
left (Grid g) = Grid (fmap back g)
right (Grid g) = Grid (fmap forth g)
```

You can define a getter and setter for the focused element:

```
set :: a -> Grid a -> Grid a
set y (Grid (Zipper ls row n rs)) = (Grid (Zipper ls (set' row) n rs))
  where set' (Zipper ls' x m rs') = Zipper ls' y m rs'

get :: Grid a -> a
get (Grid (Zipper _ (Zipper _ x _ _) _ _)) = x
```

and it may be convenient to add a function that moves the focus back
to the origin for display purposes:

```
recenter :: Grid a -> Grid a
recenter g@(Grid (Zipper _ (Zipper _ _ m _) n _))
  | n > 0 = recenter (up g)
  | n < 0 = recenter (down g)
  | m > 0 = recenter (left g)
  | m < 0 = recenter (right g)
  | otherwise = g
```

Finally, with a function that creates an all-`False` grid:

```
falseGrid :: Grid Bool
falseGrid =
  let falseRow = Zipper falses False 0 falses
      falses = repeat False
      falseRows = repeat falseRow
  in  Grid (Zipper falseRows falseRow 0 falseRows)
```

you can do things like:

```
> let (&) = flip ($)
> let testGrid = falseGrid & set True & right & set True & recenter
> testGrid
-3 [False,False,False] (False,0) [False,False,False]
-2 [False,False,False] (False,0) [False,False,False]
-1 [False,False,False] (False,0) [False,False,False]
0 [False,False,False] (True,0) [True,False,False]
1 [False,False,False] (False,0) [False,False,False]
2 [False,False,False] (False,0) [False,False,False]
3 [False,False,False] (False,0) [False,False,False]

> testGrid & right & left & get
True
> testGrid & left & right & get
True
> testGrid & get
True
>
```

The full example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

module Grid where

data Zipper a = Zipper [a] a Int [a] deriving (Functor)
  -- Zipper ls x n rs represents the doubly-infinite list (reverse ls ++
  -- [x] ++ rs) viewed at offset n
instance (Show a) => Show (Zipper a) where
  show (Zipper ls x n rs) =
    show (reverse (take 3 ls)) ++ " " ++ show (x,n) ++ " " ++ show (take 3 rs)

back, forth :: Zipper a -> Zipper a
back (Zipper (l:ls) x n rs)  = Zipper ls l (n-1) (x:rs)
forth (Zipper ls x n (r:rs)) = Zipper (x:ls) r (n+1) rs

newtype Grid a = Grid (Zipper (Zipper a)) deriving (Functor)
instance Show a => Show (Grid a) where
  show (Grid (Zipper ls x n rs)) =
    unlines $ zipWith (\a b -> a ++ " " ++ b)
              (map show [n-3..n+3])
              (map show (reverse (take 3 ls) ++ [x] ++ (take 3 rs)))

up, down, right, left :: Grid a -> Grid a
up (Grid g) = Grid (back g)
down (Grid g) = Grid (forth g)
left (Grid g) = Grid (fmap back g)
right (Grid g) = Grid (fmap forth g)

set :: a -> Grid a -> Grid a
set y (Grid (Zipper ls row n rs)) = (Grid (Zipper ls (set' row) n rs))
  where set' (Zipper ls' x m rs') = Zipper ls' y m rs'

get :: Grid a -> a
get (Grid (Zipper _ (Zipper _ x _ _) _ _)) = x

recenter :: Grid a -> Grid a
recenter g@(Grid (Zipper _ (Zipper _ _ m _) n _))
  | n > 0 = recenter (up g)
  | n < 0 = recenter (down g)
  | m > 0 = recenter (left g)
  | m < 0 = recenter (right g)
  | otherwise = g

falseGrid :: Grid Bool
falseGrid =
  let falseRow = Zipper falses False 0 falses
      falses = repeat False
      falseRows = repeat falseRow
  in  Grid (Zipper falseRows falseRow 0 falseRows)

(&) = flip ($)

testGrid :: Grid Bool
testGrid = falseGrid & set True & right & set True & recenter

main = do
  print $ testGrid & get
  print $ testGrid & left & get
  print $ testGrid & left & right & get
  print $ testGrid & right & left & get
```

Answer (score 3):

The key insight is: when you `set val True`, you're not modifying in place, but creating a copy.

`makeGrid` constructs a grid where everything is `False`, including `_left $ _right center`. When you `set val True` on the `center`, you're creating a copy `center'` where `val center' == True`. However, this copy still points to the same `_right`, which in turn still points to the same `_left`, in other words:

```
_right center' == _right center
```

and therefore:

```
_left $ _right center' == _left $ _right center == center
```

so that:

```
_val . _left $ _right center' == _val . _left $ _right center == False
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this correctly by also updating the neighbors appropriately, or something like that?

Comment: @Agnishom If you update the neighbours, then you'll have the same problem again with the neighbours of the neighbours further out, and so on. Data structures with "back references" like this are a pain with immutable types, for exactly this reason. You might be able to get this to work with laziness, at the cost of piling up thunks in *every* cell as you make modifications, but it's just a pain to work with. We generally use different techniques.